# Change countries option after init with Mapbox Geocoder

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-geocoder

I'm using the [MapboxGeocoder](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder) with the `countries` option set to a default country, but I would like to update this option if the user changes the country they want to search in.

Current code:

```js
// Add the control to the map.
const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
  marker: false,
  countries: 'nz'
});
```

I'm using the [chosen plugin from harvest](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), so I have the `on change` function working, I need to know if it's possible to change the `countries` option when they change the country so that results searched for will only return for the current country they have selected

```js
// Country selection changed
$('#country_id').on('change', function(evt, params) {
  // Check it's not empty
  if (params) {
    // code to go in here to change 'countries' option
  }
});
```

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do it now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some digging I found out how you can do this. I know this is an old question, but I'll post it anyway in case someone else ends up here trying to do the same thing! Looking at the API references here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/main/API.md#setcountries

It turns out there is a `setCountries` option - so just invoke it with:

```
placesAutocompleteBilling.setCountries(this.value)
```

with this.value being the country code (ES, IT, FR, GB etc). It seems to do the trick